# Cocos2d-XNA bouncing ball is not working

Tags: c#, cocos2d-iphone, xna, box2d

Created a sample project to test bouncing ball with Cocos2d and Box2d.

The problem is that the ball is not falling, and I can't figure out why. The gravity is set, the mass is ok, but the ball stays on the same position each step.

```
class BouncingBallLayer : CCLayer
{

    int m_screen_width;
    int m_screen_height;
    CCSprite m_ball;
    b2Body m_body;
    b2World m_world;

    public BouncingBallLayer()
    {
        AccelerometerEnabled = false;

        var screen_size = CCDirector.SharedDirector.WinSize;
        m_screen_width = (int) screen_size.Width;
        m_screen_height = (int) screen_size.Height;

        m_ball = new CCSprite("assets/soccer-ball.png");
        m_ball.Position = new CCPoint(m_screen_width / 2, m_screen_height / 2);
        AddChild(m_ball);

        b2Vec2 gravity = new b2Vec2(0.0f, -8.0f);
        m_world = new b2World(gravity);
        m_world.AllowSleep = false;

        b2BodyDef ground_body_def = new b2BodyDef();
        ground_body_def.position.Set(0, 0);

        b2Body ground_body = m_world.CreateBody(ground_body_def);
        b2EdgeShape ground_edge = new b2EdgeShape();
        b2FixtureDef box_shape_def = new b2FixtureDef();
        box_shape_def.shape = ground_edge;

        ground_edge.Set(new b2Vec2(0, 0), new b2Vec2(m_screen_width / Constants.PTM_RATIO, 0));
        ground_body.CreateFixture(box_shape_def);
        ground_edge.Set(new b2Vec2(0, 0), new b2Vec2(0, m_screen_height / Constants.PTM_RATIO));
        ground_body.CreateFixture(box_shape_def);
        ground_edge.Set(new b2Vec2(0, m_screen_height / Constants.PTM_RATIO), new b2Vec2(m_screen_width / Constants.PTM_RATIO, m_screen_height / Constants.PTM_RATIO));
        ground_body.CreateFixture(box_shape_def);
        ground_edge.Set(new b2Vec2(m_screen_width / Constants.PTM_RATIO, m_screen_height / Constants.PTM_RATIO), new b2Vec2(m_screen_width / Constants.PTM_RATIO, 0));
        ground_body.CreateFixture(box_shape_def);

        b2BodyDef ball_body_def = new b2BodyDef();
        ball_body_def.type = b2BodyType.b2_dynamicBody;
        ball_body_def.position.Set(m_screen_width / 2 / Constants.PTM_RATIO, m_screen_height / 2 / Constants.PTM_RATIO);
        ball_body_def.userData = m_ball;
        m_body = m_world.CreateBody(ball_body_def);

        b2CircleShape circle = new b2CircleShape();
        circle.Radius = 26.0f / Constants.PTM_RATIO;

        b2FixtureDef ball_shape_def = new b2FixtureDef();
        ball_shape_def.shape = circle;
        ball_shape_def.density = 1.0f;
        ball_shape_def.friction = 0.2f;
        ball_shape_def.restitution = 0.8f;
        m_body.CreateFixture(ball_shape_def);

        this.Schedule(Tick);
    }


    void Tick(float dt)
    {
        int velocityIterations = 8;
        int positionIterations = 1;

        // Instruct the world to perform a single step of simulation. It is
        // generally best to keep the time step and iterations fixed.
        m_world.Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

        //Iterate over the bodies in the physics world
        for (var b = m_world.BodyList; b != null; b = b.Next)
        {
            if (b.UserData != null)
            {
                //Synchronize the AtlasSprites position and rotation with the corresponding body
                var myActor = ((CCNode)b.UserData);
                myActor.PositionX = b.Position.x * Constants.PTM_RATIO;
                myActor.PositionY = b.Position.y * Constants.PTM_RATIO;
                myActor.Rotation = -1 * CCMacros.CCRadiansToDegrees(b.Angle);
            }
        }

    }


    public static CCScene Scene
    {
        get
        {
            // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
            var scene = new CCScene();

            // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
            var layer = new BouncingBallLayer();

            // add layer as a child to scene
            scene.AddChild(layer);

            // return the scene
            return scene;
        }

    }
}
```

By the way while debugging I get the following exceptions.

> 'Bounce.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
> 'C:\Users\Максим\Projects\games\kicknrun\branches\cocos2d\KickNRun\Bounce\bin\WindowsGL\Debug\Bounce.exe',
> Symbols loaded.
>
> 'Bounce.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Максим\Projects\games\kicknrun\branches\cocos2d\KickNRun\Bounce\bin\WindowsGL\Debug\MonoGame.Framework.dll'
>
> 'Bounce.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
> 'C:\Users\Максим\Projects\games\kicknrun\branches\cocos2d\KickNRun\Bounce\bin\WindowsGL\Debug\cocos2d-xna.dll'
>
> 'Bounce.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
> 'C:\Users\Максим\Projects\games\kicknrun\branches\cocos2d\KickNRun\Bounce\bin\WindowsGL\Debug\OpenTK.dll'
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException'
> occurred in OpenTK.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in OpenTK.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in OpenTK.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in MonoGame.Framework.dll
>
> 'Bounce.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Максим\Projects\games\kicknrun\branches\cocos2d\KickNRun\Bounce\bin\WindowsGL\Debug\box2d.dll'
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
> occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' occurred in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Although those DLLs are loaded.

---

Ok! I finally built debug versions of all the Cocos2d-xna stuff! And it appears that when the world is initizlied, the m_flags = b2WorldFlags.e_clearForces. Which leads to all the movement being reset!
Still gotta find out how to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

You should take these steps:

1: put a CCLog in the tick method just before this line `var myActor = ((CCNode)b.UserData);`
This will determine if the code has actually got to the point where it will position the ball to the b2body.
2: If the CCLog displayed in the console, that means you are doing the position calculations wrong, or you aren't retrieving the userdata properly.
If the CCLog did NOT display in the console, that means you aren't retrieving your body from the world properly.

Comment: Added CCLog, but it doesn't display anything anywhere. Gonna find out why later on. Meanwhile I'm saying that I set a breakpoint on the line you've mentioned and got it hit each time, but 'b.Position' is always the same.

Comment: Oh ok, can i ask what is the exact value of b.posision?

Comment: It is equal to initial value:
x = m_screen_width / 2 / Constants.PTM_RATIO
y = m_screen_height / 2 / Constants.PTM_RATIO
so the ball doesn't move at all.
Have an idea of building Cocos-XNA and do a full debugging.